# How to create wordlist with custom pattern

Tags: word-list

I am a newbie. I need to create wordlist with specified pattern. The pattern will look like *XXXXX00000* where X are 5 english characters (different, but can be same, small from alphabet) and 00000 are 5 numbers (0-9). (There will not be some special characters like &, $, _, -...)

Can someone help me?

It will be nice, if someone will post Terminal command. For example using **crunch**.

Thank you.

Examples:

- aklmj98765
- kjgfk11137
- hhhhd00110

Answer (score 3):

```
crunch 10 10 -t @@@@@%%%%% -o result.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I've edited the formatting of your post so that the code displays in a code block. Learn more at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hey man, good work. And if i want a condition here, that it will not save row (string) if there are more than 3 same characters, can I do it this way?

Comment: to exclude more than three consecutive letters: `crunch 10 10 -d 3@ -t @@@@@%%%%% -o result.txt`    to exclude more than three consecutive digits: `crunch 10 10 -d 3% -t @@@@@%%%%% -o result.txt`  to exclude both letters and numbers: `crunch 10 10 -d 3@ -d 3% -t @@@@@%%%%% -o result.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I made a program for you, save this as anyname.py and run. copy the output.

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers = "0123456789"

for a in range(len(letters)):
    for b in range(len(letters)):
        for c in range(len(letters)):
            for d in range(len(letters)):
                for e in range(len(letters)):
                    for f in range(len(numbers)):
                        for g in range(len(numbers)):
                            for h in range(len(numbers)):
                                for i in range(len(numbers)):
                                    for j in range(len(numbers)):
                                        print(letters[a] + letters[b] + letters[c] + letters[d] + letters[e] + numbers[f] + numbers[g] + numbers[h] + numbers[i] + numbers[j])
```

Answer (score -1):

github.com/adaywithtape/wlm does just about anything you want easy to use.I answered in the wrong place see description below.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24105607)

Comment: github.com/adaywithtape/wlm adds subtracts words, prefixes, suffixes, cleans, optimizes. Whatever you want it to do. There's nine main options each option has suboptions  at least three options. I used it  with cupp.py The Mentalist and text I copied from the internet I ran everything through WLM first prefixed a name to each word suffixed the name at the end of each word. Then I selected full list optimization it removes doubles and you can set min and max charcters. You can also add numbers and special charcters it does it all simply. Hope it helps, it's the only easy way I could find.